# How to get warning when comparing two enum value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums, gcc-warning

In this small DEMO in Objective-C:

first enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Day) {
     DaySunday,
     DayMonday,
     DayTuesday
};
```

second enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Month) {
    MonthJanuary,
    MonthFebruary,
    MonthMarch,
    MonthApril
};
```

when comparing :

```
Day sunday = DaySunday;
Month january = MonthJanuary;
if (sunday == january) {
     NSLog(@"case1 with warning");
  }
if (DaySunday == january) {
     NSLog(@"case2 without warning");
  }
```

and Xcode snapshot:
[image]

so how could i get a warning in case2?

Comment: Maybe if you use Day.DaySunday then it will show the warning. Currently its taking both the values as Integers only.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration types in (Objective-)C are very weak types. By the C Standard every enumeration constant (your `january` etc.) has an integer type, **not** the type of the enumeration. Furthermore a value of enumeration type is implicitly converted to an integer type when needed.

Clang is giving you a warning when *both* operands are of enumeration type, and it is only a *warning* as by the C Standard the comparison is a correct when between integer values.

In your `DaySunday == january` the left operand has integer type, the right operand is implicitly convert to integer type, so again this is perfectly legal and correct Standard C. Clang could *choose* to issue a warning, why it does not is probably down to a design decision, or consequence of the design, on Clang internals.

Be thankful Clang often gives warnings where Standard C does not require them, however you cannot rely on it showing all the traps in C.

To address your issue you can cast the literal to the enum type if you wish, `(Day)DaySunday == january`, but you might reasonably decide this makes C look even worse ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why this behavior is happening, but it's strange and cool. To get the warning, you have to cast `DaySunday` as type `Day` explicitly.

```
if ((Day)DaySunday == january) {
    NSLog(@"case2 without warning");
}
```

Explicitly casting `january` as `Month` won't trigger the warning, so it looks like the static analyzer is correctly treating `january` as a `Month` type (because you declared it that way), but is implicitly converting `DaySunday` to make the comparison work.

To be fair, the warning in the first case is actually not the ideal behavior, because both `Day` and `Month` are NSUIntegers and therefore are comparable. As you observe when you run this code, both comparisons are true, meaning the warning isn't actually meaningful.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change enum to int for removing Warning

```
 if ((int)sunday == (int)january) {
    NSLog(@"case1 with warning");
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how cause a warning, not how to prevent a warning.